# Django throws exception on foreign key declartion - MS SQL Server Invalid column name 'STATE'. (207)

Tags: sql-server, django

Hi I am trying to add a foreign key to one of my model classes.  For some reason this key in particular causes an exception when used in this specific class.  I can use it as a foreign key in a another one of my classes and it works fine.

I am running django 1.6.1 against MSSQL Server 12.

Here's the stack trace.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: `http://somehost:8000/admin/tracker/engagement/`

    Django Version: 1.6.1
    Python Version: 2.7.5
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'tracker')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
      432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
      52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
      198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
      29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
      25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
      1411.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
      77.         self._fetch_all()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
      854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
      220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
      710.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
      781.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
      69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
      53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
      99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
      53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py" in execute
      432.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/tracker/engagement/
    Exception Value: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'STATE'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Here's the model

```
class EngTxn(models.Model):
    eng = models.ForeignKey('Engagement', db_column='ENG_ID') # Field name made lowercase.
    date = models.DateField(db_column='DATE', blank=True, null=True, default=date.today) # Field name made lowercase.
    engagement_state = models.ForeignKey('EngagementState', db_column='STATE', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    comment = models.CharField(db_column='COMMENT', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    follow_up = models.DateField(db_column='FOLLOW_UP', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Eng_txn'
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
     return self.eng_state

class Engagement(models.Model):
    account_name = models.ForeignKey(Account, db_column='S_NAME') # Field name made lowercase.
    ibm_contact_id = models.CharField(db_column='IBM_CONTACT_ID', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    cust_contact = models.CharField(db_column='CUST_CONTACT', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    engagment_state = models.ForeignKey('EngagementState', db_column='STATE', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    start_date = models.DateField(db_column='START_DATE',  blank=True, null=True, default=date.today) # Field name made lowercase.
    planned_enddate = models.DateField(db_column='PLANNED_ENDDATE', blank=True, null=True, default=date.today) # Field name made lowercase.
    actual_enddate = models.DateField(db_column='ACTUAL_ENDDATE', blank=True, null=True, default=date.today) # Field name made lowercase.
    prime_id = models.CharField(db_column='PRIME_ID', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    backup_id = models.CharField(db_column='BACKUP_ID', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    sponsor_id = models.CharField(db_column='SPONSOR_ID', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    support_contact = models.CharField(db_column='SUPPORT_CONTACT', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    justification = models.CharField(db_column='JUSTIFICATION', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    eng_type = models.CharField(db_column='ENG_TYPE', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    app_id = models.CharField(db_column='APP_ID', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    chklist_blob = models.CharField(db_column='CHKLIST_BLOB', max_length=255, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    eng_id = models.AutoField(db_column='ENG_ID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    icn = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='ICN', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    acct_type = models.ForeignKey(Accounttype, db_column='ACCT_TYPE_ID', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Engagement'
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
     return str(self.account_name)

class EngagementState(models.Model):
    eng_state_id = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='ENG_STATE_ID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    eng_state = models.CharField(db_column='STATE', max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'EngagementState'
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
     return self.eng_state

class CuspTransaction(models.Model):
    s_name = models.ForeignKey(Account, db_column='S_NAME') # Field name made lowercase.
    txn_date = models.DateField(db_column='TXN_ENDDATE', blank=True, null=True, default=date.today)# Field name made lowercase.
    engagement_state = models.ForeignKey('EngagementState', db_column='STATE', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
      return str(self.s_name)
```

When I try and access the Engagement table from the Django admin, I get the error specified about, it complains about 'STATE' not being a valid column.  If I access the CuspTransaction table in the django admin, it works fine and they are referencing the same foreign key.  I am brand new to Django and I have no idea what's going on here.  The column obviously exists and it's accessible since it works from CuspTransaction.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure django-mssql supports django 1.6

Comment: Can you provide the code segment where you are accessing this foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

I initially did an inspect to create a model from an existing schema, I think the error I was getting had something to do with that.  Today I cleaned up the model and and worked the other way creating the database from the schema.  Everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, it is usually because I made changes to model field but forgot to makemigrations and migrate